# Windows batch script to output log

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a simple batch script to execute 2 programs. I would want to create a log file everytime this batch script is executed regardless it is success or failed.

```
@echo on

START "" /b /wait 7za.exe a C:\nexus.7z c:\nexus -pTESTING -mx7 >> c:\7zip.txt

START "" /b /wait xcopy.exe C:\nexus.7z \\ketsrv14\Software >> c:\copy.txt
```

The script above will create log for each program. Is there a way to combine the log and create only 1 log for both program?

Comment: Can't you just direct the output of both commands to the same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.  I think 7-zip will wait on it's own.
I use the `7z.exe` and don't have a `7za.exe` in mine.

```
@echo on
7z.exe a C:\nexus.7z c:\nexus -pTESTING -mx7 >> c:\7zip.txt
xcopy.exe C:\nexus.7z \\ketsrv14\Software >> c:\7zip.txt
```